# Approach to function chaining with getters and setters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I wanted to support assignment of object properties using fluent function chaining. E.g., something like:

```
foo.width(500).height(250).margin({left:5,right:10});
```

I could obviously create a function definition like:

```
margin(value) {
    this.config.margin = value;
    return this;
}
```

But what if I wanted to be able to support the above function chaining but *also* direct assignment like:

```
foo.margin = {left:5,right:10};
```

I could add this support by adding a setter like:

```
set margin(value) {
    this.config.margin = value;
}
```

But you can't have a setter and a function that go by the same name and apparently the setter only works with the literal assignment operation and the function definition only works with the fluent API approach.

Is there a way to have both in a syntactically graceful way with JS ES6?

---

I've included a fiddle which demonstrates a working example of both fluent and literal assignment operators. The only problem? I've had to resort to using different naming signature which increases the API surface ... if possible I'd like to avoid this.

http://www.es6fiddle.com/i6o0jscx/

Comment: The question is why would you add properties like that with the same names as the function? I'm guessing it's not possible, and that you should just change `foo.config.margin = 'something'` instead

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure I follow. this is a fairly common practice in other languages I think. You want to ensure setting a private/protected property is done only through a setter and you want those accessing it to have both fluent and literal assignment operators.

Comment: @ken No, it's not a common practice in other languages to have properties that behave like properties sometimes and like methods at other times. Most of the time it's one or the other. That's what you're trying to achieve here and that's why you're having trouble.

Comment: ^ what he said, and I'm not that in to ES6, but generally you don't have "private" in javascript, and you create functions that both set and get values based on the arguments passed in, like `foo.width(400)` set the value `config.width`, and `var w = foo.width()` returns the value or something similar. You can not have a property that is both a primitive and a function at the same time, no matter how fancy you get.

Comment: @JLRishe in PHP (and I believe Ruby) though it is very easy to do this and IMO it is done pretty often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use an extra two characters to *retrieve* the property values, then you can do this:

```
export class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.config = {
      width:500,
      height: 400
    };
  }

  get width() {
    return function(value) {
      if (arguments.length) {
        this.config.width = value;
        return this;
      }
      return this.config.width;
    };
  }
  set width(value) {
    this.config.width = value;
  }
}

let foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.width());
foo.width = 600;
console.log(foo.width());
console.log(foo.width(250).width());
```

Basically, the getter returns a function that sets the value if it is called with arguments, or returns the value if it is called without arguments. This is similar to the API jQuery provides for `.text()` and `.html()` and a lot of other things, but it gives you the additional option of assigning directly to the property. I wouldn't really recommend this because it's confusing to be able to do `foo.width = 5;` but not `var w = foo.width;`, but I can't see a good way to fully achieve what you're trying to do.

http://www.es6fiddle.com/i6o14n4b/

Comment: Ok thanks @JLRishe. It was a "nice-to-have" but I can live without it if its not possible.

Comment: I just really like the Fluent interface approach when you have a large number of properties to set and yet would prefer the literal assignments when there are one-offs.

Comment: @ken Well, like I said, it is possible to have both of those things, but the tradeoff is that you have to use `()` to retrieve the value. But if you are partial to the Fluent approach, I would suggest committing to that. It's more flexible and literal assignments don't really have any major benefit.

Comment: This involves more than just two extra characters, as it requires another condition block that goes beyond the method responsibility. Please look at my answer for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both. You just have to stick to the naming conventions:

```
class Thing {
    constructor() {
        this._property = 0;
    }

    get property() {
        return this._property;
    }

    setProperty(property) {
        this.property = property;
        return this;
    }

    set property(property) {
        this.setProperty(property);
    }
}
```

This way you can have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: Yes I have used this approach before and I think the naming convention is pretty clear. Still I have decided in most cases to go one way or the other but not both. Thanks for you suggestion though ... it was a good one.

Comment: OP asked for a way to be able to use the _same property name_ as both a setter method and a setter property. Your example doesn't provide that at all. Obviously, this approach works - it's extremely trivial, but my answer comes extremely close to providing what OP asked for.

Comment: @JLRishe you're right, I stand corrected.